# Convert Select Columns In Data Table With Variable Column Names

Tags: r, data.table, multiple-columns

I'm trying to convert the data of several columns in a data table into POSIXct format. I want to define which columns to convert in a character vector. Here's an example:

```
> require(data.table)
> 
> # Setting up the time data.
> BD <- as.POSIXct("2015-01-01 00:00:00", tz = "UTC")
> ED <- as.POSIXct("2015-12-31 23:59:59", tz = "UTC")
> TimeSEQ <- seq(BD, ED, by = "min")
> TimeSEQ <- as.character(TimeSEQ)
> 
> # Cutting the sequence up into 4 chunks.
> T1 <- TimeSEQ[1:131400]
> T2 <- TimeSEQ[131401:262800]
> T3 <- TimeSEQ[262801:394200]
> T4 <- TimeSEQ[394201:525600]
> 
> # Setting up the Data Table.
> DT <- data.table(Index = 1:525600, T1 = T1, T2 = T2, T3 = T3, T4 = T4)
> print(DT)
         Index                  T1                  T2                  T3                  T4
     1:      1 2015-01-01 00:00:00 2015-04-02 06:00:00 2015-07-02 12:00:00 2015-10-01 18:00:00
     2:      2 2015-01-01 00:01:00 2015-04-02 06:01:00 2015-07-02 12:01:00 2015-10-01 18:01:00
     3:      3 2015-01-01 00:02:00 2015-04-02 06:02:00 2015-07-02 12:02:00 2015-10-01 18:02:00
     4:      4 2015-01-01 00:03:00 2015-04-02 06:03:00 2015-07-02 12:03:00 2015-10-01 18:03:00
     5:      5 2015-01-01 00:04:00 2015-04-02 06:04:00 2015-07-02 12:04:00 2015-10-01 18:04:00
    ---                                                                                       
525596: 525596 2015-04-02 05:55:00 2015-07-02 11:55:00 2015-10-01 17:55:00 2015-12-31 23:55:00
525597: 525597 2015-04-02 05:56:00 2015-07-02 11:56:00 2015-10-01 17:56:00 2015-12-31 23:56:00
525598: 525598 2015-04-02 05:57:00 2015-07-02 11:57:00 2015-10-01 17:57:00 2015-12-31 23:57:00
525599: 525599 2015-04-02 05:58:00 2015-07-02 11:58:00 2015-10-01 17:58:00 2015-12-31 23:58:00
525600: 525600 2015-04-02 05:59:00 2015-07-02 11:59:00 2015-10-01 17:59:00 2015-12-31 23:59:00
> 
> # Making the names I want to convert.
> convNames <- c("T1", "T2", "T3", "T4")
> 
> #####
> # With Data Frame
> #####
> 
> # Converting to Data Frame.
> DF <- as.data.frame(DT)
> 
> # Converting the columns of convNames.
> class(DF$T1)
[1] "character"
> for (name in convNames) { DF[, name] <- as.POSIXct(DF[, name], tz = "UTC") }
> class(DF$T1)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

I'd like to be able to do this conversion in a data table, but don't know how to dynamically define the columns/apply my conversion to each column. I also provided a data frame method of doing this to further show what I'm trying to do. I've tried these methods:

```
> DT[, convNames[1], with = FALSE]
                         T1
     1: 2015-01-01 00:00:00
     2: 2015-01-01 00:01:00
     3: 2015-01-01 00:02:00
     4: 2015-01-01 00:03:00
     5: 2015-01-01 00:04:00
    ---                    
525596: 2015-04-02 05:55:00
525597: 2015-04-02 05:56:00
525598: 2015-04-02 05:57:00
525599: 2015-04-02 05:58:00
525600: 2015-04-02 05:59:00
```

However, this returns in data table class:

```
> class(DT[, convNames[1], with = FALSE])
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"
```

I do not want to explicitly put in the column names as I would possibly need to change them later. I'm just not sure how to do this in the data table package and have done a fair amount of searching; where I either didn't find a solution or didn't understand one. Thank you.

Comment: `DT[, (convNames):=lapply(.SD, as.POSIXct),.SDcols=convNames]` is the standard way but `DT[,(convNames):=lapply(mget(convNames),as.POSIXct)]` should work as well

Comment: @MichaelChirico Excuse my ignorance, but is `:=` a self referential operator. I see it used all the time with `data.table`. I just can't seem to find any explicit documentation on it (just mention it in passing). Would be the key to a lot of data table confusion for me. Thanks.

Comment: See ``?`:=` `` and [this](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reference-semantics.html) vignette

Comment: @MichaelChirico Ah, did not realize that you had to put the quotes in to access that. Thanks. Huge help! You can post your answer if you want to have this answered.